# Allow Mixed Content From Specific Website

Tags: security, http, https

I'm using an amazon affiliate link on my site but the default is to server it us as HTTP not HTTPS, when I manually change the Amazon link to HTTPS the advert does load but I get a Mixed Content warning because the image it loads is served using HTTP still.

The URL for the image it loads doesn't seem to have a HTTPS equivalent when I try it manually.

How can I fix this so I can both load the ad and retain my green padlock?

Answer (score 0):

You can't say **this page is secure** (the green padlock) **and include insecure elements**.

You need to load these images from https. No other solution.